# Trouble using scriptedmain in MinGW

Tags: gcc, attributes, mingw, weak, scriptedmain

I want to reproduce [this Perl code](https://github.com/mcandre/scriptedmain/tree/master/perl) in C, bundling API and CLI in the same C source code file ([scriptedmain](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Scripted_Main#C)). This is done in Python with `if __name__=="__main__": main()` and in gcc/Unix, this looks like:

```
$ gcc -o scriptedmain scriptedmain.c scriptedmain.h
$ ./scriptedmain
Main: The meaning of life is 42
$ gcc -o test test.c scriptedmain.c scriptedmain.h
$ ./test
Test: The meaning of life is 42
```

scriptedmain.h

```
int meaning_of_life();
```

scriptedmain.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int meaning_of_life() {
    return 42;
}

int __attribute__((weak)) main() {
    printf("Main: The meaning of life is %d\n", meaning_of_life());

    return 0;
}
```

test.c

```
#include "scriptedmain.h"
#include <stdio.h>

extern int meaning_of_life();

int main() {
    printf("Test: The meaning of life is %d\n", meaning_of_life());
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to compile with gcc/Strawberry, I get:

```
C:\>gcc -o scriptedmain scriptedmain.c scriptedmain.h
c:/strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): In function `main':
/opt/W64_156151-src.32/build-crt/../mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And when I try to compile with gcc/MinGW, I get:

```
$ gcc -o scriptedmain -mwindows scriptedmain.c scriptedmain.h
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text+0x104): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I get GCC in Windows to recognize the `__attribute__((weak))` syntax?

Also, G++ shows the same error.

Comment: I think I've narrowed down the question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396333/does-windows-have-a-declspec-equivalent-to-unix-gccs-attribute-weak

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works in Windows and in Unix: Simply wrap `main()` in preprocessor instructions that omits it unless explicit compiler flags are set.

scriptedmain.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int meaning_of_life() {
    return 42;
}

#ifdef SCRIPTEDMAIN

int main() {
    printf("Main: The meaning of life is %d\n", meaning_of_life());

    return 0;
}

#endif
```

Now `main()` will be entirely omitted unless you compile with

```
gcc -o scriptedmain -DSCRIPTEDMAIN scriptedmain.c scriptedmain.h
```

This code is safe to import into other C code, because the preprocessor will strip out `main()`, leaving you to code your own main. The best part is that this solution no longer depends on obscure compiler macros, only simple preprocessor instructions. This solution works for [C++](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Scripted_main#C.2B.2B) as well.

Comment: This is called "special sauce", and is frowned upon by some developers.

Comment: Name something that *isn't* frowned upon by some developers.

Comment: I don't see why this would be better than simply putting `main` in a file by itself.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't good practice in C regardless of operating system.  Best practice in C for anything complicated enough to be worth separating into library and driver is to put `main` in a file all by itself.

Comment: I concede that this may not be best practice, or even common practice, but my question is not *should I*. My question is *how can* this be done in Windows? If I need some sort of Makefile trickery to get this to work, so be it.

Comment: I am not a windows guy, but as far as I know, it has no concept whatsoever of weak symbols.  In other words, what you want to do is just not possible.

Comment: If either Strawberry Perl's GCC or MinGW's GCC were to add syntax for `__attribute__((weak))`, this would work, because that's the difference that allows it to work in Unix.

Comment: They can't do that, because the OS doesn't support it.  As far as I know, anyway.