# Does Windows have a __declspec equivalent to Unix GCC's __attribute__((weak))?

Tags: c, windows, unix, macros, mingw

I want to import some C code but override its `main()` function. I can do this in Unix by prefacing the C code's main declaration with `__attribute__((weak))`, however, this won't compile in Windows, because neither Strawberry Perl's GCC nor MinGW's GCC recognize `__attribute__((weak))`.

Reading the docs online, `__declspec` seems to function similarly. Is there a `__declspec` equivalent to Unix GCC's `__attribute__((weak))` macro?

This is a more specific version of an [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395130/trouble-using-scriptedmain-in-mingw/12395171) question I posted.

Comment: Why not change the EXE entry point name instead?

Comment: In MSVC linker options, you can change the entry point name to something else, and name your REAL main function differently.

Comment: Can you help me to do this either in a Makefile, or the code itself? I don't want to force the code to have to use MSVC++. Hopefully we can get this to work in Cygwin.

Comment: In link.exe, it is /ENTRY. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e(v=vs.80).aspx 
I am sure makefile can get it thru, though I am not an expert on makefiles.

Comment: Would I supply `/entry` when compiling scriptedmain.exe, when compiling test.exe, or both?

Comment: Just saying GCC isn't only usable in UNIX. Works great for me all the time in Windows.

Comment: That's why I'm asking this: When I use `__attribute__((weak))` in GCC in Unix (Mac OS X as it happens), everything works just fine. When I try to compile the exact same C code with GCC (MinGW and Strawberry Perl) in Windows, compilation fails. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395130/trouble-using-scriptedmain-in-mingw/12395171

Comment: I have no idea what are these EXEs you mentioned..

Comment: Pavel, let's start over. I want to replicate this Perl code behavior, but in GCC/Windows-valid C:

https://github.com/mcandre/scriptedmain/tree/master/perl

If you run the scriptedmain file, it prints "Main: The meaning of life is 42". If you run the test file, it prints "Test: The meaning of life is 42". For Perl, these files would be scriptedmain.pm and test.pl. For C, these files would be scriptedmain.c, compiled into scriptedmain.exe; and test.c, compiled into test.exe. This works when compiled by a true Unix GCC compiler (eg MacOSX gcc using macro). I want C code that works in Windows.

Comment: I found a way to hide `main()` using [simple preprocesser instructions][1].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12397886/350106

Answer (score 1):

There's another way with MSVC that I *think* would work if you care to use it.

```
/*
 * pWeakValue MUST be an extern const variable, which will be aliased to
 * pDefaultWeakValue if no real user definition is present, thanks to the
 * alternatename directive.
 */

extern const char * pWeakValue;
extern const char * pDefaultWeakValue = NULL;

#pragma comment(linker, "/alternatename:_pWeakValue=_pDefaultWeakValue")
```

See [this old SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290587/gcc-style-weak-linking-in-visual-studio) for some other options.

Comment: I need to weaken the `main()` function, not an extern const variable.

Answer (score 0):

There's also `__declspec(selectany)`