# Does Visual C++ provide a language construct with the same functionality as `__attribute__((alias))` in GCC?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, visual-c++

[`__attribute__((alias))` means:](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)

> alias ("target")
>
> The alias attribute causes the declaration to be emitted as an alias for another symbol, which must be specified. For instance,
>
> ```
>   void __f () { /* Do something. */; }
>   void f () __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__f")));
> ```
>
> defines `f` to be a weak alias for `__f`. In C++, the mangled name for the target must be used. It is an error if `__f` is not defined in the same translation unit.
>
> Not all target machines support this attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Windows have a \_\_declspec equivalent to Unix GCC's \_\_attribute\_\_((weak))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396333/does-windows-have-a-declspec-equivalent-to-unix-gccs-attribute-weak)

Comment: `#pragma comment(linker, "/alternatename:f=__f")` must be (where in place f and __f must be exactly mangled names)

Comment: @RbMm: That doesn't look lkke a duplicate.

Comment: @R.. - may be i mistake. however this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12397639/6401656 is answer for current question

Comment: @RbMm: "same solution works" doesn't imply *question* is duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this for C. This is supported for x86 and x64 for msvc v19.15.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void __f() { puts("This function is aliased"); }

void f();

#pragma comment(linker, "/alternatename:f=__f")

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

See the compiled demo [here](https://godbolt.org/z/BFnP8n).

I have tested this in Visual Studio 2017 with `/TC` option.

Comment: compile nothing prove here. need link, because `f` if not found redirected to `__f` at link time. also `#pragma comment(linker, "/alternatename:f=__f")` only for *x64* and *c* code. for *c++* code symbols will be mangled `?f@@YAXXZ=?__f@@YAXXZ` must be. for *c* and *x86* also will be mangle depend from calin convention. say `_f=___f` for __cdecl or `_f@0=___f@0` for __stdcall and `@f@0=@__f@0` for __fastcall

Comment: I tested it on my PC. But I obviously could not link it here. rextester has an older version of VC++ compiler.

Comment: your current code will be ok only if you compile as *c* code and target platform *x64* otherwise you got unresolved external symbol