How to unify 'weak' and 'packed' between different compilers?
I'm developing an application protocol stack. It needs the 'packed' feature so that the compiler does not automatically expand the protocol message structure, and the 'weak' feature to allow users to override the default function implementation with their own.
I only know that my favorite compiler GCC provides relevant features, but users hope that they can use Clang and MSVC.
I found some answers on Google and Stack Overflow, but they are incomplete. It looks like Clang can use GCC's directives directly, but MSVC doesn't seem to support 'weak'.
Thanks.

Note there are many compilers aside from GCC, Clang and MSVC and remember that billions of processors per year are embedded ones where C is quite popular.  Strive for portability versus compiler specifier features.

"It looks like Clang can use GCC's directives directly." ==> Yes, Clang supports GNU C's attributes, and so does ICX.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537964/visual-c-equivalent-of-gccs-attribute-packed for packed attribute and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396333/does-windows-have-a-declspec-equivalent-to-unix-gccs-attribute-weak for weak attribute. The relevant answer for weak applies to variables, and I believe that should work for you.

@dsyx Consider posting the answer instead of adding the code in the question. Also consider specifying a link to the documentation for selectany. And you can add ...defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER) after defined(__clang__). Also note that you do not require the underscores after attribute. __attribute((...)) is all that's necessary.

I think you should consider not using either of these features, especially if it is your intention to use the protocol to communicate data between programs compiled with different compilers or between different machines. For example, if your protocol includes a long integer, that will take up 8 bytes in clang and gcc, but only four bytes in MSVC. You should probably even set out an explicit endianness and packed structs won't do anything for you there.

@Harith According to Attribute Syntax, it should be __attribute__ ((attribute-list)). Why do we need to remove the underscore after attribute?

@JeremyP The fields in my message structure use fixed-length types provided by the stdint.h header file, such as uint16_h.
packed is used to prevent the compiler from filling spaces between fields, such as the compiler will fill 3 bytes between func and id in the structure struct{uint8_t func; uint32_t id; uint16_t op;}.

@dsyx My comment still stands. I think you should be explicitly packing a buffer yourself rather than relying on the compiler's interpretation of packed. I think the API should provide the ability to supply callback functions rather than use weak for customisation.

Thanks to @Harith.
I wrote the following code based on the suggestions:
#ifndef __WEAK
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
#define __WEAK __attribute__((weak))
#else
#error "Unsupported compiler: Please define __WEAK"
#endif
#endif

#ifndef __PACKED
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
#define __PACKED(__Declaration__) __Declaration__ __attribute__((__packed__))
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#define __PACKED(__Declaration__) __pragma(pack(push, 1)) __Declaration__ __pragma(pack(pop))
#else
#error "Unsupported compiler: Please define __PACKED"
#endif
#endif

I tried it and found that __declspec(selectany) cannot be used as a replacement for weak.

Without proper serialization of your data, you can't handle big-endian and little-endian systems.  And once you do proper serialization of data, packed structures are not needed.

@AndrewHenle Do you mean to implement a function to serialize the message structure into a byte stream? That's one way, but it requires an extra copy.
